# How do I filter resources provided by dependencies in Maven?

Tags: java, maven

Let's assume I have a Java project called com.example:awesome-project, which has a dependency called com.external:awesome-library.

If this awesome-library has resources like configuration.xml, how do I filter this resource so that Maven property placeholders are replaced properly before I use it in the project's code?

Things like `<tag name="${groupId}:${artifact}">` need to be changed to `<tag name="com.example:awesome-project">`, for instance.

Assumptions:

- The awesome-library is external to this project, and is not built by
  me.
- I have no knowledge about the variable placeholders used in the
  .xml files. All I know is that they are defined somehow by Maven.
  Let's take project meta-data, for example ${artifact}, as an example.

Comment: One thing I'm trying is to unpack and then filter, but I'm not sure if it is going to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [dependency:unpack](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/unpack-mojo.html), which will extract resources, by default to `${project.build.directory}/dependency` (which you can change if you want).

Then, either use either:

- [resources:copy-resource](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/copy-resources-mojo.html) and define your filtering in that plugin's execution and also configure its [resources](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/copy-resources-mojo.html#resources) configuration to point to `${project.build.directory}/dependency`
- it might be simpler to just put a `resources` element in your POM's `build` section and point it to `${project.build.directory}/dependency` with appropriate filtering.  Though if you want the standard `src/main/resources` as well you will need to put it there also.

Comment: I did as you proposed here. The only thing is that dependency:unpack should be done before resource filtering is done (which is process-resources), in generate-resources for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this solution:

1. Create parent (builder) project, and place in it constant which will be replaced in resource file:

   ```
    <properties>
        <some.constant>123</some.constant>
    </properties>
   ```
2. Define both projects as modules in parent project:

   ```
    <modules>
      <module>../awesome-project</module>
      <module>../awesome-library</module>
    </modules>
   ```
3. In my-configuration.xml place constant reference as

   ```
   ${some.constant}
   ```
4. In awesome-library.pom config filter processor (for example, suppose that my-configuration.xml is placed in src/main/resources/META-INF:

   ```
    <build>
       <resources>
           <resource>
               <directory>src/main/resources/META-INF</directory>
               <targetPath>META-INF</targetPath>
               <filtering>true</filtering>
               <includes>
                   <include>**/my-configuration.xml</include>
               </includes>
           </resource>
   ```
5. Run `maven clean install` in parent project.

Comment: Unfortunately awesome-library is something external, which I don't build. I don't know what Maven variables it is using either, some obvious things used by the library are project meta-data (like artifact Id, version number, etc).

Comment: Can you show pom.xml of library project if it exists? And my-config file too.

Comment: Let's assume pom.xml file for the library doesn't exist, and the configuration file is as little as what I have posted in the question, only a <tag>.

Comment: And the only relationship between the project and library is that the former has the latter as a standard Maven dependency.

Comment: I suppose, that only maven-assembly-plugin can helps in your case. You will need to create meta-project, which goal will provide an opportunity for edit config file "on the fly" by maven.

Comment: Thanks Alexander, I'll give it a try as well.